# TinyDB remove WHERE multiple values are true

Tags: python, python-3.x, tinydb

In Python, I'm trying to remove an entry from TinyDB where 2 values match.

Example DB:

```
{
    "_default": {
        "1": {
            "GuildID": 123,
            "RoleName": "role"
        },
        "2": {
            "GuildID": 321,
            "RoleName": "role"
        }
     }
```

If I do

```
db.remove(where('RoleName' == role))
```

It will remove both entries, but I don't want that. I want to match on `GuildID` and `RoleName`

I thought this would work, but apparently not

```
db.remove(where('RoleName' == role) & ('GuildID' == 321))
```

The above query doesn't find any values at all in the DB, but I want it to delete entry `2`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, I used TinyDB's `Query` function

```
from tinydb import Query
QueryBuilder = Query()
db.remove((QueryBuilder.RoleName == role) & (QueryBuilder.GuildID == 321))
```